How do I make sure that something is in Path on Github Actions?
I'm having trouble with my GitHub Action to test a Python module on Windows. To test the module, I need to install ffmpeg and make sure that it's on Path but no matter what I do in the workflow file or the Python script that installs ffmpeg, I can't seem to get it to appear on Path.
I'm installing ffmpeg through this script, which uses this approach to add it to Path:
def add_path_to_environment(path):
    '''Adds a filepath to the users PATH variable after asking the user's consent'''
    os_path = os.environ['path']
    if not os_path.endswith(';'):
        os_path += ';'
    command = f'[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","{os_path}{path}","User")'
    print('\n\n')
    print(command)
    print()

    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['powershell', command])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.stdout.decode())

My latest attempt in the workflow is to use this:
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\FFMPEG\bin", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
echo $env:Path
ffmpeg -version

Which I found here, but I've also tried just using $env:Path += ";C:\FFMPEG\bin"
Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could get ffmpeg on Path?

If you haven't tried it. I'm using FedericoCarboni's setup-ffmpeg@v3 in my GitHub Action script, and it's working fine testing my Python project. This action puts the FFmpeg path to the system path, so you should just be able to call ffmpeg or ffprobe from your PowerShell.
I have the following entry in my action.yml file:
      - name: Set up FFmpeg
        uses: FedericoCarboni/setup-ffmpeg@v3
        with:
          architecture: x64
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


This might be a better option than my workaround posted below, I'll give it a try, thanks.

I'm not entirely sure why (probably because permissions are limited) but I can't set the environment variable for Machine or User. I can, however, set it for Process so I just set it that way, like this:
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\FFMPEG\bin", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)

Then I made sure that all the commands that required ffmpeg were performed in the same runtime.

There is no permissions problem. What you're looking for is an in-process update to the Path environment variable, which the Machine and User scope values by design do not provide.
While your solution does work, the simpler, PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent is $env:Path += ';C:\FFMPEG\bin'.
(Your question states that you tried that, but given that your solution here and the latter are equivalent, there must have been a confounding factor).
See this answer for details.


Preface:

The premise of the question - which is implicitly confirmed by your own answer - is that the Python installer script is called from a PowerShell session and that you want the latter to see the value of the Path environment value modified by the installer.

While it is true that the Python installer script - which of necessity run in a child process - fundamentally cannot update the calling process' environment, it doesn't even attempt that: it only updates the persistent, user-level definition of the Path environment variable in the registry, which only future processes see.[1]

Therefore, repeating the modification performed by the installer in the registry for the current process's Path value is necessary, as shown below.

kesh's answer may offer an alternative approach that obviates the need for this additional step.
The value of this answer is in showing the PowerShell-idiomatic way to update process-level environment variables and in explaining the concepts underlying environment-variable updates on Windows in general.




tl;dr
Use the following, which is the concise, PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent of your own solution:
# Same as:
#   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
#      'Path', 
#      $env:Path + ';C:\FFMPEG\bin', 
#      [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process
#   )
$env:Path += ';C:\FFMPEG\bin'

This appends C:\FFMPEG\bin to the list of search paths  for the current process (PowerShell session) only, so that subsequent calls to ffmpeg - by executable name only - in the same session succeed.
Targeting the current process is all that is needed, because it is your installer script that took care of modifying the Path value persistently, by targeting the persistent user-level scope ([EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process), for future processes[1]; how the installer script updates the value in that scope is inappropriate, but that's a separate issue; see next section.
An alternative that avoids hard-coding the directory path is therefore to refresh the value directly from the registry, though note that this will discard any in-process-only modifications to $env:Path made in the same session:
$env:Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
            [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'

The above implies that the additional, current-process modification is only necessary if the persistent modification performed by an installer hasn't taken effect yet; in a normal installation scenario, all that is needed is to start a new PowerShell session (see next section for constraints).

Background information:
The above is the PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent of the following System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable .NET API call:
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
  "Path", 
  $env:Path + ';C:\FFMPEG\bin', 
  [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process
)

The Process enumeration value of type System.EnvironmentVariableTarget[2] specifies that the variable should be set for the current process only.
That is, the environment modification is transitory, and goes out of scope when the current process exits.
By contrast, the [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User and [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine scopes - available on Windows only - create or modify an environment variable persistently, for the current user and the local machine, respectively.
These persistent definitions are stored in the registry, at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, respectively.
As the hive part of the latter registry key implies (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), in order to modify variables in the [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine scope you need to run with elevation (run as administrator).
Note:

Targeting these scopes does not also make the modification for the current process, which is why the process-scope modification shown at the top is necessary too.

A persistent change made via [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable() is announced via a WM_SETTINGCHANGE broadcast message, in response to which applications that listen to it can refresh their process-scope environment from the registry, to make the change take effect.
This what the Windows (GUI) shell (the system component that provides the desktop, taskbar, and File Explorer) does, though few other applications do.
Thus, in the user's current logon session, it is only future PowerShell sessions started via the Windows shell that are guaranteed to see the persistent changes right away. When in doubt, log off and back on, or reboot.


Caveat:

The System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable .NET API should not be used to modify the persistent definition of the special Path environment variable - see this answer for details.

In short: What the linked installation script does is inappropriate for two reasons:

It converts the original registry value, which is of type REG_EXPAND_SZ, where Path entries can reference other environment variables, to a static string, REG_SZ.
By basing the updated value on the current process-scope value (os.environ['Path'], the Python equivalent of PowerShell's $env:Path), which is a composite of the persistent user- and machine-scope values, the machine-scope entries are in effect duplicated in the persistent user scope.




[1] However, in a CI/CD environment such as GitHub Actions, where each run starts with a clean slate, the concept of a persistent update doesn't apply. Separately, it is possible to design applications to be notified of persistent environment changes, allowing them to refresh their environment in-process. This is what the Windows shell does, for instance, as discussed in the bottom section.
[2] As an aside: You could shorten [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process (which itself is short for [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process, because PowerShell allows you to omit the System. namespace component) to 'Process', i.e. a string, which PowerShell would automatically translate into the enumeration value.

As I said in the question, I had already tried using $env:Path += ';C:\FFMPEG\bin', which hadn't worked. I addition, I also mentioned in my own answer that I don't think that I had permissions to change environment variables for User or Machine but modifying them for Process worked fine and I didn't really need the change to persist anyway as this was only a simple testing workflow.

@Alarm-1202, you said that in your question, but it is contradicted by your own answer. As  noted in this answer, your solution and $env:Path += ';C:\FFMPEG\bin' are the same: PowerShell translates the latter into the former behind the scenes. The rest of the answer provides general information about the scopes of environment-variable modifications (which you seemed to have misconceptions about), and also explains that and why the installation script you're using inappropriately modifies the persistent user-scope Path definition.

I'm sure it does work the same behind the scenes, but if your advice doesn't work in practice then it's pretty worthless if you ask me.

@Alarm-1202: Your question betrays fundamental misconceptions about how environment variables work on Windows. I thought those misconceptions were worth clearing up, to the (potential) benefit of not just you, but future readers as well. If my advice didn't work in practice, it would amount to a PowerShell bug of epic proportions, and there is no such bug. It is trivial to verify that the commands are equivalent in practice. On the off chance that you do find them not to be equivalent in your environment, I encourage you to file a bug report at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Actually, the reason this solution doesn't work is because it only sets the "search paths for the current process". In the OP's context "the current process" is a Python subprocess, not the Python main process. So, the main process never receives this path in its env path.

So, if OP wants to set the path in Python, the best approach is the PowerShell to return the FFmpeg path, and add to the os.env['Path']. This will ensure that the Python process gets the FFmpeg path.

@kesh: The premise of the question - which is implicitly confirmed by Alarm-1202's own answer - is that the Python installer script is called from a PowerShell session. Indeed, a child process cannot update the calling process' environment, but said script doesn't even attempt that (it only updates the persistent, user-level definition of the Path variable in the registry), which only future processes see.

@kesh: Thus, in order to add the ffmpeg directory also to the calling PowerShell process' Path value, a process-level definition is also needed,
which can be done by hard-coding the directory path, as in Alarm-1202's own solution as well as the PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent shown here, or, preferably, by manually refreshing the Path definition from the registry,
as now also shown in this answer.

P.S., @kesh: I don't doubt that your alternative approach may be the better solution, but the point of this answer
is to address the conceptual confusion around environment variables exhibited in the question.

@mklement0 - Honestly, I've only read your tl;dr lines and skimmed your exchanges with OP above before I dropped my comment above. So I apologize if I sounded redundant. (Now I read it a bit more, I think we are saying the same thing but mine with a simplistic story based on my own experience.) I personally try to avoid modifying the registry-level path at all cost, but for a use in github action, it may not matter as it's a throw-away virtual system.

Understood, @kesh. Yes, there's no point in making persistent changes in such environments. Fundamentally, any installer that must run in a child process faces the limitation of not being able to update the immediate caller's environment too. The way to avoid this limitation for any given environment is a plug-in of sorts that can either directly run in-process or launches the target code in another child process that inherits the environment modified by the plug-in (which then obviously can not modify the original caller's environment). It sounds like your solution provides that.
